# Не могу сохранить данные в Core Data

Tags: swift

Не могу сохранить данные в Core Data - подскажите пожалуйста, что не так - я создал переменную в классе - но я так понял ей не присваиваются свойства объектов, которые нужно сохранить.

import UIKit
import CoreData
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
class AddVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

```
var words : Word?
override   func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ParametrsTV.delegate = self
    ParametrsTV.dataSource =self
}






let questions = ["What does mean this word?","Which transcription?","What to connect this pronunciation?","How to write pronunciation for native language?","What part of speech?","Which synonyms can be chosen?","How is used in conversation?","How is used in text?","How is used in musition and film?","How could you apply it?"]

@IBOutlet weak var NameWord: UITextField!


@IBOutlet weak var ParametrsTV: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var SaveWord: UIButton!

@IBAction func InputNameTW(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBAction func SaveButn(_ sender: Any) {
    if NameWord.text != ""{
        save { (complete) in
            if complete {
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

}
func save(completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }

    let  word = Word(context: managedContext)

        word.name = NameWord.text
        word.translation = words?.translation
        word.associationByPronunciation = words?.associationByPronunciation
        word.formOfSpeech = words?.formOfSpeech
     do {
            try managedContext.save()
            print("Successfully saved data.\(word.name, word.formOfMusitionAndCinema,word.pronunciation,word.translation,word.associationByPronunciation)")
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Could not save: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(false)
        }

    }



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return questions.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellAdd") as! CellAddWord
    cell.labelAtribute.text = questions[indexPath.row]
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:

        if cell.labelAtribute.text  == "What does mean this word?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = words?.translation}
    case 1:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "Which transcription?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.pronunciation}
    case 2:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "What to connect this pronunciation?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.associationByPronunciation}
    case 3:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "How to write pronunciation for native language?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.nativePronunciation}
    case 4:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "What part of speech?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.partOfSpeech}
    case 5:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "Which synonyms can be chosen?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.synonymsForLeanLang}
    case 6:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "How is used in conversation?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.formOfSpeech}
    case 7:

        if cell.TextAttributes.text != "How is used in text?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.formOfText}
    case 8:

        if  cell.TextAttributes.text != "How is used in musition and film?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.formOfMusitionAndCinema}
    case 9 :

        if  cell.TextAttributes.text != "How could you apply it?" && cell.TextAttributes.text != ""{
            cell.TextAttributes.text = self.words?.whereMeeting}
    default:
        print("Don't save")
        }
    return cell

}
}
```